# How to extract field value in splunk

Tags: splunk

How to extract field values in Splunk using rex field=_raw

`logAlias=Overall|logDurationMillis=1298|logTimeStart=2019-10-15_00:01:12.821|logTimeStop=2019-10-15_00:01:14.119|UniqueId=8aa984556db09592016dcd93b5a708ee`

Path : /var/opt/pivotal/logs
Logfile : file.log

Splunk query:

`index=main source="/var/opt/pivotal/logs/file.log*" 
| rex field=_raw "logDurationMillis= (?<numbr>\d+)" 
| where numbr>950 
| stats count(numbr) As FailedFraudAPITxns`

Comment: You appear to have answered your own question.  What, if anything, is wrong with the query?

Comment: You have a space after `=` that does not exist in your sample.  `field=_raw` is not actually needed since it is the default.

Comment: Good eye!! There was an extra space after = 
Thanks @PM77-1